# code completion do not work in Nodeclipse 0.4

Tags: eclipse, code-completion, jsdt, nodeclipse

Are there something that I messed up, when installing Nodeclipse 0.4 so I can not do code completion since my code is worked.

---

---

**EDIT**:

[image: current view of Nodeclipse]

as you can see at picture, 
- the red one is Node mode in Eclipse Kepler which enable after Nodeclipse installed 
- the blue one is Java EE IDE in Eclipse which I use as to installed Nodeclipse 
- the yellow one is Node code in Eclipse which default exist if I chose the example 
- the green is Node code class representative.

if I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> in `console.`, there is not any code completion showed up which should showed up cause I already have JsHint v. 0.9.6

if I follow [instructions of installation](https://raw.github.com/Nodeclipse/eclipse-node-ide/master/ENodeIDE.p2f).. then..

I got this list..  (**note:** the disables means I already installed it.)

[image: list of the rest]

then.. I got this message..

[image: error when installed the rest]

---

---

**ANOTHER ADDITIONAL EDIT**:
as [the comment of Nodeclipse developer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/24843712?noredirect=1),

if I reproduced but to installed JSHint alone then it goes with this message..

[image: when installed JSHint alone]

Thanks, 
Ahmad

Comment: Which version of Nodeclipse are you using?

Comment: @[Pushkar](http://stackoverflow.com/users/441368/pushkar-gupte) `0.4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is work in progress on content assist for Node.js modules
[Content assist for Eclipse JSDT based Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738788/content-assist-for-eclipse-jsdt-based-editor)

fork with work in progress:
https://github.com/Enide/nodeclipse-1/compare/Nodeclipse:master...master

[image]
<sub>(source: [nodeclipse.org](http://www.nodeclipse.org/img/Completion-for-base-Node.js-modules.PNG))</sub>

Comment: Node.js base module support since 0.9

Answer (score 1):

Code completion is depending on what code you have. Could you please share your snippet?
Version 0.4 has Eclipse JSDT standard functions. Node.js specific libraries support is not yet implemented.

Opened issue for new feature is [#50 support for node.js style module definitions](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues/50)

[console is defined inside node.js](http://nodejs.org/api/stdio.html), and as such is not yet supported.

Comment: @Ahmad Azwar Anas I have checked in my Eclipse and updated answer.

Comment: thanks for any help. I use [cloud 9](https://c9.io/) for temporary. hope no one hacked it. ^^

Answer (score 1):

For second part of the question (about installation using Enide `.p2f` file):

> if I follow [instructions of installation](https://raw.github.com/Nodeclipse/eclipse-node-ide/master/ENodeIDE.p2f).. then..

some update sites like StartExplore are not stable and often unavailable

So if there is problem installiing, The [recommendation](http://www.nodeclipse.org/enide) would be to install less plugins in one time (only 1 at a time, for example)
(Then there is way to know what exact plugin update site is unavailable at this time)

For nodeclipse itself latest Eclipse (Like 4.2.2 IDE for Java EE Developers) is recommended & enough.

Comment: what are sites now exist?? cause I installed `NJSDTdoc` alone still produce same error..

Comment: You actually don't have NJSDTDoc, but standard JSDT.

Comment: NJSDTDoc is only for NJSDT and is not project of Nodeclipse organization