# NodeClipse - Autocomplete - Mongoose - Javascript library

Tags: javascript, eclipse, node.js, mongoose, nodeclipse

I'm trying to get autocomplete to work on nodeclipse or eclipse for js projects.  Specifically autocomplete on mongoose objects (as I'm just learning mongoose).

I thought if I add the js file as a library then it should be able to auto-complete...but I can't get it to work.

I'm not setting the javascript library properly (not sure if it is at the folder level or js level).

Has anyone had any success to get the autocomplete to work with nodeclipse or eclipse?

I've already seen this [posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17059917/code-completion-do-not-work-in-nodeclipse)

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar issue recently. I've installed [VJET](http://eclipse.org/vjet/) an Eclipse plugin that allows code completition.

Here is an overview of the [code completition feature.](http://wiki.eclipse.org/VJET/Code_Assistance_Features)

You also need some libraries to allow code completition. You can find these libraries [here](https://github.com/eclipse/vjet.typelibs)

Import the library you need as a Project and link it to your Project. Then autocompletition will magically work!